# How to create a ROS2 simulation environment in Docker?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-humble, arm-cpu

**What I'm trying to do?**

I would like to run `ROS2` in a `Docker` container using `Gazebo` for visualisation. I have achieved this before whilst working on a computer using Linux, however I now need to run this container from `Apple Macs` using `M1` and `M2` chips (with `ARM64` architecture).

**What I've done?**

So far I have created the following Dockerfile:

```
# 1. Specify ROS2 base image
FROM arm64v8/ros:humble-perception

# 2. Set up environment variables for GUI
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1

# 3. Add dependencies for Gazebo installation
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \    
    x11-apps && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# 3. Install Gazebo
RUN wget https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.gpg -O /usr/share/keyrings/pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg && \
    echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable $(lsb_release -cs) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list > /dev/null && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ignition-fortress && \
    apt-get clean

# 4. Set up entry point
CMD ["bash"]
```

This is named `simulation` and builds without error. I run it using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1. Obtain the IP address

ip=$(ifconfig en1 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}')

# 2. Allow access to X server

xhost + $ip

# 3. Run the Docker container (X11 Test Command: "xeyes", Gazebo Command: "ign gazebo")

docker run \
  -it \
  --rm \
  -e DISPLAY=$ip:0 \
  --network=host \
  --privileged \
  simulation \
  /bin/bash -c\
      "
       xeyes
      "

# 4. Revoke X server access
xhost - $ip
```

**What works?**

When I start the container I run the `xeyes` application, everything works great and I can prove that the `X11` forwarding works as a graphic showing the eyes that following the mouse is displayed in its own window.

**What doesn't work?**

When I run `ign gazebo` I get the following messages:

```
192.168.86.50 being added to access control list
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[GUI] [Err] [Application.cc:801] [QT] Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile) 
Stack trace (most recent call last):
#31   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0", at 0xffffaaff5ab7, in rb_vm_exec
#30   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0", at 0xffffaaff088b, in 
#29   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0", at 0xffffaafedefb, in 
#28   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0", at 0xffffaafebef3, in 
#27   Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ruby/3.0.0/fiddle.so", at 0xffffa7365d93, in 
#26   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0", at 0xffffaafb8b13, in rb_nogvl
#25   Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ruby/3.0.0/fiddle.so", at 0xffffa73656cb, in 
#24   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8", at 0xffffa7343a93, in 
#23   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8", at 0xffffa7346e0f, in 
#22   Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libignition-gazebo6-ign.so.6.14.0", at 0xffffa6831fcf, in runGui
#21   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libignition-gazebo6-gui.so.6", at 0xffffa66700c3, in ignition::gazebo::v6::gui::runGui(int&, char**, char const*, char const*, int, char const*)
#20   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libignition-gazebo6-gui.so.6", at 0xffffa666e05f, in ignition::gazebo::v6::gui::createGui(int&, char**, char const*, char const*, bool, char const*, int, char const*)
#19   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libignition-gazebo6-gui.so.6", at 0xffffa666bd8f, in ignition::gazebo::v6::gui::launchQuickStart(int&, char**, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#18   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0xffffa3f441cb, in QCoreApplication::exec()
#17   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0xffffa3f3b06b, in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
#16   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0xffffa3f9b523, in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
#15   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0xffffa2d82f13, in g_main_context_iteration
#14   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0xffffa2ddaeab, in 
#13   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0xffffa2d85a6f, in g_main_context_dispatch
#12   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5", at 0xffff9c87f267, in 
#11   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5", at 0xffffa42e9393, in QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
#10   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5", at 0xffffa4312dfb, in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processExposeEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::ExposeEvent*)
#9    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0xffffa3f3cb8f, in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)
#8    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5", at 0xffffa53e2abf, in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
#7    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5", at 0xffffa431e5f3, in QWindow::event(QEvent*)
#6    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5", at 0xffffa4eebb57, in 
#5    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5", at 0xffffa4eea5b3, in 
#4    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5", at 0xffffa4ee903b, in QSGRenderLoop::handleContextCreationFailure(QQuickWindow*)
#3    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0xffffa3d30f63, in QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const
#2    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0xffffaac4712f, in abort
#1    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0xffffaac5a67b, in raise
#0    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0xffffaac9f200, in 
Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 46 0)
Escalating to SIGKILL on [Ignition Gazebo Server]
192.168.86.50 being removed from access control list
```

**Any suggestions for fixes?**

Can anyone suggest how I can alter my `Dockerfile` or run script to solve these errors and correctly display a `Gazebo` GUI?

Answer (score 2):

Gazebo needs not only X11 but also OpenGL to work. (See the error above `Failed to create OpenGL context...`

OpenGL support is provided by your graphics card.

To that end you need to make sure that your graphics card is available inside your container. This requires mounting the hardware as well as potentially checking that the driver software is installed inside.

To that end I'd suggest looking at a tool like [`rocker`](https://github.com/osrf/rocker) that helps with these aspects. (NB: I'm the primary author.)

If I run it with just X11 gazebo will crash:

```
$ rocker --x11 gazebo
Extension volume doesn't support default arguments. Please extend it.
Active extensions ['x11']
Writing dockerfile to /tmp/tmp51u0gikq/Dockerfile
vvvvvv
# Preamble from extension [x11]


FROM gazebo
USER root
# Snippet from extension [x11]


^^^^^^
Building docker file with arguments:  {'path': '/tmp/tmp51u0gikq', 'rm': True, 'nocache': False, 'pull': False}
building > Step 1/2 : FROM gazebo
building >  ---> 9731a1b00210
building > Step 2/2 : USER root
building >  ---> Using cache
building >  ---> a18dbe6a582a
building > Successfully built a18dbe6a582a
Executing command: 
docker run --rm -it  -e DISPLAY -e TERM   -e QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1   -e XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.dockerivd91zwi.xauth -v /tmp/.dockerivd91zwi.xauth:/tmp/.dockerivd91zwi.xauth   -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix   -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro  a18dbe6a582a 
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
```

But if I mount the video card for my system it will not crash.

```
$ rocker --x11 --device=/dev/dri/card0 gazebo
Extension volume doesn't support default arguments. Please extend it.
Active extensions ['devices', 'x11']
Writing dockerfile to /tmp/tmpqx3xxe9m/Dockerfile
vvvvvv
# Preamble from extension [devices]

# Preamble from extension [x11]


FROM gazebo
USER root
# Snippet from extension [devices]

# Snippet from extension [x11]


^^^^^^
Building docker file with arguments:  {'path': '/tmp/tmpqx3xxe9m', 'rm': True, 'nocache': False, 'pull': False}
building > Step 1/2 : FROM gazebo
building >  ---> 9731a1b00210
building > Step 2/2 : USER root
building >  ---> Using cache
building >  ---> a18dbe6a582a
building > Successfully built a18dbe6a582a
Executing command: 
docker run --rm -it --device /dev/dri/card0   -e DISPLAY -e TERM   -e QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1   -e XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.docker_4p4bm7v.xauth -v /tmp/.docker_4p4bm7v.xauth:/tmp/.docker_4p4bm7v.xauth   -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix   -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro  a18dbe6a582a
```

You can see the options that it's adding to the docker command line to add the video card.

This is the specific video card for my system (intel integrated) `rocker` offers an option `--nvidia` option for NVIDIA drivers which is tested on Ubuntu systems.

Running on your Apple hardware is untested. You will need to figure out how to get your graphics card into the container.

Also I'd recommend using the approach from rocker for `X11` forwarding as well. Opening everything up and giving `--privileged` gets rid of a lot of the benefits of containers. Or just use rocker. rocker has options for `--net=host` `--privileged` which you're already using. It's not tested on MacOS but PRs to improve the behavior would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds very useful. I'm struggling to repeat what you've shown though. I tried to install rocker in my Dockerfile and then run the container using the command:

`sudo dockerd &> dockerd-logfile && \ rocker --x11 gazebo'

I don't get any output. Could you suggest what an appropriate Dockerfile and run script might look like?

Comment: rocker should be installed run on your host not inside the container. You can get it from pypi with `pip` It replaces the docker run command. `rocker --x11 --device=/dev/**** --privileged --net=host -- simulation xeyes` should be equivalent of your whole bash script if you find the GPU device ID for your system.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. How can I find the Mac M1 or M2 GPU device ID?

Comment: You'll probably want to find a docker on MacOS forum to ask that question.

Answer (score 1):

When I use some rendering capabilities such as RViz or Gazebo. I use [rocker](https://github.com/osrf/rocker) which allow to include very easily x11 and NVIDIA support

Install Rocker

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-rocker
```

Run the container with rocker to visualize the GUI

```bash
rocker --x11 --nvidia simulation
```

If you want to use NVIDIA, please install first nvidia-docker

Comment: This sounds interesting. I’m using a Mac that doesn’t have an NVidia graphics card. Is your suggested option still applicable?

Comment: you can try, `rocker` should work with MAC